# Adding a ManyToManyField to an existing model with django/south give me an error

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

Here is my model in production (in selfcare.apps.support.models) :

```
class Document(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('HSI', _('Internet')),
        ('ITV', _('Television')),
        ('VOIP', _('Phone')),
        ('MAIL', _('Email')),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='support_documents')
```

I want to add to the existing Document model the following line :

```
network = models.ManyToManyField('selfcare.apps.auth.models.Network')
```

Here is the model of the Network class (in selfcare.apps.auth.models):

```
class Network(selfcare.libs.core.utils.SettingHelper, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_index=True, default='')
    operator = models.ForeignKey(Operator)
    setting = generic.GenericRelation(Setting)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.code, self.operator.code)
```

When I try a schemamigration with south, I get this error message :

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
support.document: 'networks' has an m2m relation with model selfcare.apps.auth.models.Network, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

Both app are in INSTALLED_APP.
Both app are already managed by south.

Comment: What exactly is in `INSTALLED_APPS`? Note that you're not supposed to have `models` in that M2M field reference.

Comment: selfcare.apps.auth and selfcare.apps.support are in INSTALLED_APPS. I've changed the added line to  networks = models.ManyToManyField('selfcare.apps.auth.Network') but the result is the same

Comment: Possible not a great idea to call your app 'auth', as that is the same name as the django.contrib.auth app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas Orozco, I did find my mistake ! 
This line was not correct :

```
network = models.ManyToManyField('selfcare.apps.auth.models.Network')
```

I correct it like that :

```
network = models.ManyToManyField('auth.Network')
```

Then the migration did work with south !